# how to insert checkbox as array into mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I don't know why it's not being inserted. it doesn't show an error or anything so i couldn't figure out the problem.

the tags [ '61c2102d165a5af742091a70', '61c37621165a5af742093a1a' ].

here is my insert function:

```
insert: async(req,res)=> {
    const {userid,tags}=req.body;
    console.log("userid", userid)
    console.log("tags", tags) //tag [ '61c2102d165a5af742091a70', '61c37621165a5af742093a1a' ]
    try {
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            userid,
            { $push: { tags: {$each : tags } }} ,
        );
        
        return res.status(200).send({msg:"success"});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({ msg: "Something went wrong" });
    }
}
```

my user schema:

```
tags: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Tag'
    }]
```

tag schema:

```
const TagSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    type: {
        type: Object,
    },
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});
```

Most codes i saw do it like that but i couldn't figure out why mine isn't working

Comment: try adding exec at the end of findandupdate.

User.findByIdAndUpdate(....).exec();

Comment: Unfortunately did not work

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using async, you can make use of await to see it if is saved or not. Rewriting logic in this way you can catch saved instance and return success or failure.

```
insert: async(req,res)=> {
const {userid,tags}=req.body;
console.log("userid", userid)
console.log("tags", tags) //tag [ '61c2102d165a5af742091a70', '61c37621165a5af742093a1a' ]
const doc = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    userid,
    { $push: { tags: {$each : tags } }} ,{new:true}
);
if (!doc) return res.status(500).send({ msg: "Something went wrong" });
return res.status(200).send({msg:"success"});
```

}

Comment: when i console log doc it is null don't know why

Comment: also when i console log type of tags it is "object", how can i change it to array and insert it into  users model?

Comment: No need to worry about getting type as object for array. Node is using javascript engine and you will get type as object for array. Can you try with User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userid}{..condition},{new:true}).

Comment: okay thank you it worked but now every time i submit it adds them multiple times like this tags: [
        new ObjectId("61c37621165a5af742093a1a"),
        new ObjectId("61c5b35a165a5af742095c3a"),
        new ObjectId("61c37621165a5af742093a1a"),
        new ObjectId("61c5b35a165a5af742095c3a")
        ]